# Let $X \neq \emptyset$, define the relation$A\sim B$ if there exists a bijection $f : A \to B$, Show that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $X$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

A question on my last proofs midterm, I know I must prove injectivity and surjectivity, but there aren't really any obvious conditions or descriptions on S that helped me to manipulate it to try and prove that this is onto and one-to-one.  Can somebody help me get started on this question?

Answer (score 5):

**HINT:** The composition of bijections is a bijection; and the inverse of a bijection is a bijection. I will leave you to prove reflexivity on your own.